# filter key value with multiple JSON? (geocoding)

Tags: javascript, json

multiple JSON filter with one function.

I am doing geocoding project now.. i can filter with 1 json file.. but how about have multiple json file with filter ?

**state1.json**

```
[{
    "no": "1",
    "location": "Acheh Baru",
    "postcode": "32000",
    "postOffice": "Sitiawan",
    "state": "Perak"
}, {
    "no": "2",
    "location": "Akauntan Negeri",
    "postcode": "30594",
    "postOffice": "Ipoh",
    "state": "Perak"
}, {
    "no": "3",
    "location": "Alor Kechor",
    "postcode": "32800",
    "postOffice": "Parit",
    "state": "Perak"
}]
```

**state2.json**

```
[
    {
        "no": "1",
        "location": "Air Putih",
        "postcode": "83400",
        "postOffice": "Seri Medan",
        "state": "Johor"
    },
    {
        "no": "2",
        "location": "Akauntan Negeri",
        "postcode": "80594",
        "postOffice": "Johor Bahru",
        "state": "Johor"
    },
    {
        "no": "3",
        "location": "Aked Mara",
        "postcode": "83100",
        "postOffice": "Rengit",
        "state": "Johor"
    }
]
```

**state3.json**

```
[
    {
        "no": "1",
        "location": "Akauntan Negeri",
        "postcode": "05594",
        "postOffice": "Alor Setar",
        "state": "Kedah"
    },
    {
        "no": "2",
        "location": "Alor Gelegah",
        "postcode": "05400",
        "postOffice": "Alor Setar",
        "state": "Kedah"
    },
    {
        "no": "3",
        "location": "Alor Ibus Tepi Laut",
        "postcode": "06600",
        "postOffice": "Kuala Kedah",
        "state": "Kedah"
    }
]
```

I able to filter with 1 json to get value that i want :

```
import data from '../json/state1.json';

let jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);
let parsedData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

function findObjectByKey(parsedData, key, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
        if (parsedData[i][key] === value) {
            return parsedData[i]['state'];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

let obj = findObjectByKey(parsedData, 'codes', "34200");

console.log(obj); //output Perak
```

## My question

How to filter with `state2.json` and `state3.json` together? if I type `83100`, should output `Johor`. I tried to import all data in one variable but still not able to filter the value.

for some reason, I need to separate multiple JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import all the JSON data in your file. Using `array#concat` join all the data in a single array. Using `array#find` you can get the first matched object for a given key and value.
If you are interested in getting all the matched object, replace the `array#find` with `array#filter`.

```
import data1 from '../json/state1.json';
import data2 from '../json/state2.json';
import data3 from '../json/state3.json';

function findObjectByKey(data, key, value) {
  return data.find(state => state[key] === value);
}

let obj = findObjectByKey([].concat(data1,data2,data3), 'postcode', "34200");
```

Comment: redundant `return` in the arrow function?

Comment: Updated the solution.